# VSCode Integrated Terminal creates a separate window

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

Just installed VSCode and git bash.

I've added the following lines to the settings.json file:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "D:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe" 
}
```

When I press Ctr+` to open the integrated shell window, instead of opening inside the main editor at the bottom it opens a new window:

[image: Git Bash Winow]

Why isn't it showing in the usual place?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to this [vscoode GitHub Issue (#7286)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7286#issuecomment-224183210):

> ... `git-bash.exe` is a Windows application (with WinMain as entry), but `bash.exe` is a console application (with main as entry). To be used as integrated shell, the executable must be a console application, so that stdin/stdout/stderr can be redirected.

The recommended approach is to use:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

Answer (score 6):

**My Solution:**

1. Open settings
2. Deactivate: `Windows Enable Conpty`

[image: Windows Enable Conpty]

Comment: thank you, this worked perfectly for me, all the other answers didn't work

Comment: after hours of troubleshooting, this worked for me

Comment: @HassanALAMI I am unable to find "Windows Enable Conpty". How can I find it?

Comment: @ShivamGupta
Ctrl + Shift + P > "Preferences: Open User Settings" > search for "Windows Conpty"

Answer (score 2):

I was infact looking for the solution to this exact problem. @JBD said it correctly however I would just like to add that the git-bash.exe file is kept seperate in the normal program folder of git.

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "D:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe" 
}
```

but what you need to link within vs Codes settings is a different file which will enable git bash to run within the vs code terminal. The path to that is in the "bin" folder within the "Git" folder.

```
{
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "D:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe" 
}
```

This will allow your git bash to run from within the terminal window of VS Code

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the accepted answer is no more relevant on the latest version of VSCode (I'm using 1.74.3). It will throw an error something like below.

> This is deprecated, the new recommended way to configure your default
> shell is by creating a terminal profile in
> `#terminal.integrated.profiles.windows#` and setting its profile name
> as the default in `#terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows#`. This
> will currently take priority over the new profiles settings but that
> will change in the future.

The issue is, there are two types of bash application available in Git,

1. git-bash.exe (opens up in a separate window)
2. bash.exe (opens up in VSCode terminal window)

The bash.exe is located inside **/bin** folder.

It requires below config in the settings.json

```
 "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "Bash": {
      "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Git-2.35.1.2\\bin\\bash.exe"
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, this should be the verified answer !

Answer (score 1):

For those using Git installed via Scoop, just use the Scoop's installation folder path:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "${env:USERPROFILE}\\scoop\\apps\\git\\current\\bin\\bash.exe",
```

Answer (score 1):

i was also face this issue but i solved this issue

change path of git bash

"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "D:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"

and uncheked legacy console check box in cmd
[Image of cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okjsY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about all but in my case, git bash location is changed into the appdata instead of programming file, so you can use same as mentioned:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Users\\{user_name}\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
```