# How to run c++ programe in different window(console) in vs code like code blocks

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, visual-c++, codeblocks

I want to run a c++ file in another window through vs code like code blocks. Like I want to display the output in a different window(console) using vs code. Please help:)

Comment: Does this solve your question? [VSCode Integrated Terminal creates a separate window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47474379/vscode-integrated-terminal-creates-a-separate-window)

Comment: Edit your `launch.json` file to open a new `cmd` or `powershell` program running your program?

Comment: @risingStark no

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude can you give me any tutorial about it please